# Converting VP9 webm to VP8

Tags: ffmpeg, video-conversion, encoding, matroska, webm

I wonder how can I convert VP9 webm to VP8 with FFmpeg or Matroska (matroska would be better) without changing any kind of setting? I just want the output to be exactly same as the input but as VP8 only.

Comment: It's been literally 8 days and still no response

Answer (score 0):

Convert from VP9 to VP8:

```
ffmpeg -i input.webm -c:v libvpx -crf 10 -b:v 1M -c:a libvorbis output.webm
```

Taken from [the documentation](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/VP8).